# getting unanted charcaters in cache value using dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dalli

I am trying to read the cache value set in Rails.cache , i am working on rails 3.1 and using dalli.

When i execute this block i am getting some unwanted characters in response

Here is the code block

```
@total_count = Rails.cache.fetch(count_key){ 
  connection.select_rows("select FOUND_ROWS()").first.first.to_s
}
```

and the output i am getting is

```
���Uc��T�022b�bsu���#
```

When i try to use insepect on total_count i get the below output

```
"\x1F\x8B\b\x00\xAC\xF9\xC5U\x00\x03c\xE1\xF0T\xE2022b\xB3bsu\x03\x00\x9A\x84\xF8#\r\x00\x00\x00"
```

i am expecting a interger value like 128 or 222. Can anyone please suggest what could be going wrong here, Thanks.

Comment: *FOUND_ROWS()* is used to return **previous** *SELECT* row count number, what is the previous SELECT in your case?

Comment: Whats the result of executing `connection.select_rows("select FOUND_ROWS()").first.first.to_s` outside the Rails.cache block?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, i restarted the memcache server and that reolved my issue, Thanks.